# Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, gmail, starttls

I am having the following code

```
            ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
            ini_set("smtp_port","587");

            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
            $config['_smtp_auth']=TRUE;
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'sender@gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '60';
            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
            $config['mailtype'] = "html";

            $this->email->initialize($config);

            $this->email->from('sender@gmail.com', 'Sender');
            $this->email->to('receiver@gmail.com');

            $this->email->subject('This is my subject');
            $this->email->message('This is the content of my message');

            if ( ! $this->email->send())
            {
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
            else
            {
                echo('DONE');
            }
```

But when the code executes, I am getting the following error

> Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. qd9sm8462833pbb.31

I have used

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

in my controller's constructor. But I am unable to send email from localhost. What can be the solution to send email? What changes do I need to make?

Comment: It looks like your code is attempting to deliver over plain text SMTP, not using TLS or SSL secured connection.

Comment: @RomanR. How to use TLS or SSL secured connection?

Comment: I don't have the answer for "how" part (specifically to `php`), however the error message clearly tells "why".

Comment: @RomanR.see I have config $config['mailtype'] = "html";
 so my attempt is not to deliver over plain text SMTP. Its mailtype is HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set "Enable IMAP" option in your Gmail account.

It is in the Mail options.

And change your port to 465 ...

```
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
```

to

```
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Ariel! Please, add a description to your answer, explaining how does this solve the question! You can read some more info, how to crack an answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: Please note that port 465 is deprecated now that the STARTTLS option is available. Should use port 587.

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls'; // or html
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer solve my problem thanks,I tried all multiple ways but not solved.